# How to reproduce this "offset behavior" programmatically?

Tags: ios, uikit, interface-builder

Since iOS 7, Apple encourages developers to show content behind navigation bars and other translucent elements.
Let's say that I have a view controller embedded in a navigation view, adding to this view controller a map view and extending the edges of the map view to the bounds of the screen (so even **behind** the navigation bar) gives the expected effect : the navigation bar blurs the content of the map view.
But iOS also does something else : although the map itself is rendered *behind* the navigation bar, if a ui element the user must see or touch (for example the compass) is actually offseted so that it isn't hidden by the navigation bar ; a picture is worth a thousand words :
[image]

What I would like to know is what property of the map view I should use to make it behave like this programmatically ? (because if I manually add a translucent view on the top of my map, the compass will be hidden, so I would like to be able to do that) ? This question also applies for other kinds of views, such as table views, is it the same principle ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UIScrollView` and its subclasses (`UICollectionView`, `UITableView`), setting the `contentInset` to something like, say, `UIEdgeInsetsMake(64.0 /* TOP */, 0.0 /* LEFT */, 44.0 /* BOTTOM */, 0.0 /* RIGHT */);` would be the way to go.

You can inspect the `UIViewController`'s properties `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` to determine how much you have to inset.

For `MKMapView`, I've tried adding it programmatically and it appear that it adjusts the frame of the compass and the "Legal" label automatically. I would say that it takes `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` into account to layout the button and label.